# No networking on boot after upgrading Kubuntu to 13.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, kubuntu, 13.04, ethernet

I upgraded Kubuntu to 13.04 today. I'm using an ethernet connection. On every boot, networking service is running and everything is configured properly, but it can't establish a connection. I have to

sudo service networking restart

on every startup. How can I fix this? I could create a script to restart networking that runs at startup, but I'd rather find a solution than a workaround.

Can you help me?

P.S.: I found out that sometimes it boots up normally, but there's no log I found that includes different information when networking is "frozen". When it is, though, my CPU reaches over 90% for hp-systray (hp-update) is trying to look for updates but can't understand that network is unreachable.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Similar to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/292966/switched-from-ubuntu-to-kubuntu-no-more-network-folders-in-dialogs).

Comment: Could you include the `/var/log/daemon.log`, `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: I'm sorry Braiam. I've already installed Kubuntu from scratch and everything works perfectly, now. I absolutely needed a working connection, so I went for the easy way.